# How can I annotate a class in pypy?

Tags: python, annotate, pypy

I am using pypy to translate some python script to C language.
Say that I have a python class like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
    def func(self): 
        pass
```

I notice that `A.func` is a unbound method rather than a function so that it cannot be translated by pypy. So I change the code slightly:

```
def func(self): 
    pass
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
A.func = func
def target(*args):
    return func, None
```

Now `func` seems to be able to be translated by pypy. However when I try `translate.py --source test.py`, an exception `[translation:ERROR]  TypeError: signature mismatch: func() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)` is raised. I notice that it might because I haven't annotate `self` argument yet. However this `self` have type A, so how can I annotate a class?

Thank you for your reading and answer.

Comment: What's the `target()` function for?

Comment: What line does the `translation:ERROR` apply to? I don't see any calls to `func()` in the code. What does the error have to do with "annotating" a class?

Comment: Somehow I'm not surprised that you're have difficulty translating object-oriented code with classes into C which is a procedural language without a class type.

Comment: FYI everybody: From <http://codespeak.net/pypy/dist/pypy/doc/translation.html#annotator> "The major goal of the annotator is to "annotate" each variable that appears in a flow graph. An "annotation" describes all the possible Python objects that this variable could contain at run-time, based on a whole-program analysis of all the flow graphs -- one per function."

Answer (score 5):

Essentially PyPy's entry point is a function (accepting sys.argv usually as an argument). Whatever this function calls (create objects, call methods) will get annotated. There is no way to annotate a class, since PyPy's compiled code does not export this as API, but rather as a standalone program.

You might want to for example:

```
def f():
    a = A()
    a.func()
```

or even:

```
a = A()
def f():
   a.func()
```

in which case a is a prebuilt constant.

Comment: Thank you, fijal. I do know that when I call a function from the entry point that function will get annotated. However when I call that function only once, arguments will became constants in the generate code. Say a function `def f(a): return a + 1`. If I call it in the entry point like `f(1)`, it will generate a `2` instead of a function `long pypy_g_f(long a){return a + 1}`, So I have to call it twice or more to make things right. It's kind of complicated. So I was trying to generate function directly using `translateshell.py` and that comes my question

Comment: translatorshell is deprecated anyway. If you want to export some interface there is translator/goal/sharedpypy.py and translator/c/dlltool.py which are a start of what you want if you want to embed an RPython program. They'll give a sane names for functions for example. I've used this to embed pypy in webkit.

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting a [staticmethod](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#staticmethod) or a [classmethod](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod)?

Comment: Both staticmethod and classmethod are OK for me, and classmethod might be better

Comment: If you're just not caring about `self` and don't need to do anything with the class, use `staticmethod`.

Comment: Sorry may be I didn't make myself clear. I did care about `self`. it has to be a specific class. I need to interact with the member of the class

Comment: If you're caring about `self` in the method then you can't do `A.func()` - you'd need to give it an `A` instance as that first parameter, e.g. `A.func(A())`. Do you understand the basic Python way of doing these things? Is your code working in CPython?

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I just want to check the correctness of function `func`. Since there are lack of tools for python, I want to translate my function to C firstly and then check the C code. So it's kind of that I don't care about whether `func` is a bound method of class A or just a function.

Comment: Then we come to the main question: what precisely do you mean by "annotate"? Do you mean what [PEP 3107](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) says, or something else?

Comment: No, by "annotate" I mean a function provided by pypy. It specify the type of arguments for a function. Maybe we were talking about different things ^_^